# I have a personal taxonomy i.e car and i want to have a template to show car relevant post

Tags: wordpress, custom-post-type, categories, taxonomy

I have created a custom post type named `vehicles` and there are different categories for that like `trucks`, `cars`, `vans` etc. I have created a taxonomy named `vehicles-categories` and now I want to show posts from taxonomy like `cars` on specific page which will show only posts from that certain category/taxonomy.

I have written WordPress custom loop but it does takes me to `index.php` page while I want different styles for that `cars` page.

Can anyone figure out what's am I doing wrong?

Comment: Good edits @LoicTheAztec. Also, requests for urgency may be trimmed here - they are strongly discouraged.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to create a custom template for your taxonomy to show posts from that specific taxonomy.

In your case if you want to show posts from term "car" then your template name will become `taxonomy-vehicles-categories-car.php` and WordPress will show posts on this page (you can style and get data according to your needs in this template).

Similarly, you can create `taxonomy-vehicles-categories.php` page to show posts from this taxonomy and can code this page to show posts as you want.

For further and in-depth understanding about how WordPress uses taxonomy template files visit the [official codex page](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/template-files-section/taxonomy-templates/).